# How to programmatically open and use the "Compare files" window in Visual Studio TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-addins

I am currently working on a TFS build back add-in for Visual Studio 2013 that will allow users to merge and check in changesets to multiple service packs more easily. The utility is a pop up windows form that connects with the TFS server. At the merge overview screen, which displays all of the service packs the user will be merging/checking in to with all of the changesets and corresponding filepaths, there are buttons next to each individual filepath. When the user clicks a button, using information I already have stored (file's source path and the target source path), I want to programmatically open and display the comparison of the two files in Visual Studio.

If someone could point me in the right direction of what to look into it would be greatly appreciated as I have been spinning my wheels trying to find the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

This article shows how to use the `vsDiffMerge.exe` tool to do exactly what you're talking about I think.

http://roadtoalm.com/2013/10/22/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-and-merging-tool-for-local-files/